# Splitting a string into a fixed number of elements

Tags: python, string, list

I need to split a string in two. If the string doesn't include the delimiter, I need the second string to be `None`. The following code works but seems much too verbose for what it does. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
def splitter(item):
    elements = item.split('_')
    first = elements[0]
    if len(elements) == 1:
        elements.append(None)
    second = elements[1]
    return first, second

mylist = ['do_this', 'do_that', 'do_somethingelse', 'stayput', 'sleep']

for item in mylist:
    print(splitter(item))

# Output:
# ('do', 'this')
# ('do', 'that')
# ('do', 'somethingelse')
# ('stayput', None)
# ('sleep', None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems OK.

You could do this :

```
def splitter(item, delimiter):
    if delimiter in item:
        return  tuple(item.split(delimiter))
    else:
        return (item, None)

mylist = ['do_this', 'do_that', 'do_somethingelse', 'stayput', 'sleep']

for item in mylist:
    print(splitter(item, "_"))
```

By the way, are you 100% sure you will have only one "_" in your strings ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping there would be a one-liner for this but your suggestion is shorter and much nicer, regardless. BTW, yes, only one underscore there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```py
def splitter(item):    
    parts = item.split('_')
    return parts + [None] * (2 - len(parts))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple-enough one-liner for each item in the list:

```
mylist = ['do_this', 'do_that', 'do_somethingelse', 'stayput', 'sleep']
for item in mylist:
    item_1, item_2 = item.split('_')[0], item.split('_')[1] if len(item.split('_')) != 1 else None
    print(item_1, item_2)

#Output:
#do this
#do that
#do somethingelse
#stayput None
#sleep None
```

Here is a full one-liner for the whole list that puts each pair into a tuple within a list:

```
newlist = [(item.split('_')[0], item.split('_')[1] if len(item.split('_')) != 1 else None) for item in mylist]

#Output:
#[('do', 'this'), ('do', 'that'), ('do', 'somethingelse'), ('stayput', None), ('sleep', None)]
```

It should be easy enough to modify these so the output is in the format you want (list, tuple, etc).